# Connecting Analog Mixer to Audio Interface

Tags: daw

I have a analog mixer would like to connect it to a audio interface. The purpose of this is for social media live streaming. I'm eyeing the focusrite 2i2. Drum mics, guitar, bass  keyboard and 3 mics are connected to my analog mixer.

My question is , is focusrite 2i2 enough for this?

Answer (score 2):

The 2i2 has two identical inputs and 2 preamps so it should work just fine. Keep in mind that will have to mix everything down to a stereo mix on your mixing board and send that mix to the 2i2 so you won’t be able to do any individual level adjustments after the fact.

Comment: Basically all the controls are done in the mixing board? Will you have an option to have additional line tracks on your software with focusrite to have controls on each line inputs?

Comment: With that many inputs, let’s say for example 5 drum mics plus the other instruments and mics you’re looking at about 12 inputs. The 2i2 can accept and record 2 inputs at a time so the only way you can record or stream live with the 2i2 is mixing down to 2 tracks before you get to it. Once you’re in the 2i2 you can use whatever plug ins and controls are available to you within whatever software you’re using on those two tracks. If you want all those inputs to go separately into the computer you will need to get an audio interface that has as many inputs as you need.